Galera and Docker, 4 nodes between 2 servers, all connected
The goal is to have 4 galera nodes. 2 on server A, 2 on server B, all connected and in docker.
Its easy to set up two nodes on two different servers:
wsrep_cluster_address = "gcomm://servera.com,serverb.com"
wsrep_cluster_name    = "galera-cluster-radius"
wsrep_node_name       = "mariadb1"
wsrep_node_address    = "servera.com"

You just set the wsrep_cluster_address to both servers dns. And have the wsrep_node_address set to the dns of the server the node is on.
Its easy to set up two nodes on the same server:
wsrep_cluster_address = "gcomm://"
wsrep_cluster_name    = "galera-cluster-radius"
wsrep_node_name       = "mariadb1"
wsrep_node_address    = "mariadb1"

You have the wsrep_cluster_address set to empty and wsrep_node_address set to the mariadb docker container name.
My question is: How do i get both of these to work together? What do I have wsrep_cluster_address and wsrep_node_address set to?

You either put two services on different ports on the same server, in which case the wsrep_cluster_address contains a port number (and port contains the number), or better, put two IPs on each server (and use bind-address). Its unclear what your achieving as a hardware failure has two nodes, which isn't a quorum (over 1/2), so its not online (PRIMARY).

@danblack eventually ill scale to three i just need to get 2 working first. Could you maybe provide an example of a full cnf file?

Can the port be any port that the docker service exposes?

The internal/external port and that Galera uses perception of internal port as external mean that container based sst require a bit more thought/reliability than what I have time to answer at the moment. Two instances on bare metal deconflicting port/socket/datadir would be easier to get started in the first instance.

1-1 mapping between internal and external ports is a good option.
